# Lighttpd Proxy to Service on Another Port

Tags: proxy, port-forwarding, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I have an issue, which I hope is common enough to be resolved quickly. Specifically, I have a server on which I wish to host several web-applications at the same time for my own personal use. I would like it to be well-organized however.

My current approach is to install/setup each of the web apps with their own instance of a lighttpd server running over HTTP on a non-standard port (8080, 8081, 8082, and etc). I then use the system's lighttpd server as a proxy to each of these web apps. So for example `myurl.com/tt-rss/` proxies to `127.0.0.1:8080/tt-rss/` and so on. The "main" lighttpd instance will also be the one responsible for running HTTPS (access to the ports used by the web-apps is restricted to localhost only) so I figure this is a convenient way to handle HTTPS all in one place as opposed to having to configure it for every single web-application on its own.

The problem I am having is as follows: I am trying to run the Shout webapp for IRC, which runs on Node.js and by default simply runs on port 9000. The problem is that the url for this is `myurl.com:9000` and not `myurl.com:9000/shout/` which means that if I used the proxying approach described above, that would mean that I can only proxy `myurl.com => 127.0.0.1:9000`, but this is not conducive to running other similar applications on my server. I would like to be able to have this proxying setup: `myurl.com/shout/ => 127.0.0.1:9000/` I presume that I need to use `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` in concert for this, but I am unsure as to how to do this. I was hoping someone could help out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I did figure it out eventually, but not exactly the way I had intended in the original question. Basically, I created a new hostname: `shout.myurl.com`, pointed it using my domain name provider towards the same server, and then added the following to my configuration in lighttpd:
        `$HTTP["host"] == "shout.myurl.com" {
            proxy.debug = 1
            proxy.server = ( "" => ( ("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9000) ) )
        }`

Comment: Thanks @RedHack. Much appreciated. I think this will come in handy for proxying my Asp.Net Core app.

Comment: 8 years later and this solved my issue Had to run a NodeJS service on port 3000. I kept putting the port in quotes in the '10-proxy.conf' file. removed quotes and it worked perfectly